# Unable to create inner class object in java

Tags: java

I am unable to create an inner class object in java:

```
package OOO;

class Car{
    class Engine{

        void display() {
            System.out.println("this is inner diaplay() method");
        }

    }
}

public class Sample8InnerClassCar {
    Car c = new Car();
    Car.Engine e = c.new Car.Engine();
}
```

its throwing me an error : cannot allocate member type Car.Engine. could someone please help me to understand more?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class

Comment: Try `c.new Engine();`. Using `c` already opens its scope.

Comment: also you can use "static" keyword for inner class

Comment: @DmitryGorkovets No you can't. 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms'. If you make it 'static', it ceases to be 'inner', and the semantics change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
Car.Engine e = c.new Engine();
```

Complete code snippet:

```
package OOO;

class Car {
    class Engine {

        void display() {
            System.out.println("this is inner diaplay() method");
        }
    }
}

public class Sample8InnerClassCar {

    Car c = new Car();
    Car.Engine e = c.new Engine();
}
```

Comment: Car.Engine e = new Car().new Engine(); also worked :)